# Как принудительно закрыть консольное приложение?

Tags: c#

Делаю запись видео с экрана с помощью SharpAvi. В определенный момент времени хочу послать сообщение о завершении процесса записи. Только не пойму как) Это же консольное приложение.. Поднимать http-сервер тоже считаю неразумным. Подскажите как быть?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rec = new Recorder(new RecorderParams("out.avi", 1, SharpAvi.KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg, 70));

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Stop...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    // Finish Writing
    rec.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Исходя из заголовка - `Environment.Exit(0);`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а как программа узнает тот момент когда мне это нужно?

Comment: ну так где надо, там и пропишите выход